# Upload picture in React with Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

How can I add an upload image to a React form ?

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
                <label>Titre</label>
                <input className="form-control" 
                type="text"
                ref="title"
                name="titleLoi"
                value={this.state.titre}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>

                <label>Description</label>
                <input className="form-control"
                type="text"
                ref="abstract"
                name="abstractLoi"
                value={this.state.abstract}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>

                <button className="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
            </form>
```

I saw on Atmosphere a package okgrow:image-upload. Is it only using an external package that I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting your form to handle file uploads by adding the enctype attribute and adding a file input will allow you to select a file to upload:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <input className="form-control"
        type="file"
        ref="uploader"
        name="image"
        onChange={this.uploadFiles.bind(this)}/>
</form>
```

How you style this and handle this file on the server are different questions.